# PHP PDO SELECT statement: Compare VARCHAR as INT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with a generic structure.
In a column called `myvalue` I store information that can either be an integer, string or a date.
In order to make it generic, the column `myvalue` is a `VARCHAR`. This means, when I save an integer, it is still stored as a string.

Now, I am executing a `SELECT` on the table. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myvalue > 10 AND username = 'foo'
```

Imagine we have 2 rows for the user `foo`: `5` and `20`.
Executing this query directly, will give me the right result (returning `20`).

Now, I execute the query through PDO:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myvalue > ? AND username = ?";
$params = array(10, 'foo');
$adapter->fetchAll($sql, $params);
```

The result returns `[5, 20]` as if PDO compared strings.

**How can I tell PDO to do a numeric comparison?**

Comment: This should work just fine. What happens when you place 10 directly for the question mark ?

Comment: It works when I place it directly (see first example)

Comment: No that's not what I meant and said. Leave foo for the question mark.

Comment: We need to see your implementation of "fetchAll()" - what type is "$adapter"?  What are all the optional arguments to "fetchAll()"?  It looks like you've written your own wrapper.

Comment: Fair enough. It's Zend Framework's implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$adapter->fetchAll` is a big black mystery box to us, so I'll speculate that you're naïvely doing something like this inside it:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

This indeed treats all params as strings. If you want parameters to be explicitly treated as integers, you need to bind them appropriately:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mutable WHERE myvalue > ? AND username = ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, 'foo', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

That probably means you'll have to rewrite or discard your wrapper a bit.

Alternatively, you could offload this cast operation to MySQL (though it seems misplaced IMO):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mutable WHERE myvalue > CAST(? AS SIGNED INTEGER) AND username = ?";
$params = array(10, 'foo');
$adapter->fetchAll($sql, $params);
```

Comment: Agreed - the question needs to provide far more information.